# Checking if URL has changed for use within a session check

Tags: java

The code below works to increase the counter for every page a visitor goes too however i'm needing to work out how to make it so it doesn't allow an increase in counts on the same page over one (to stop someone spamming refresh and increasing the view count). Is there a way to check if the URL has changed within a java servlet?

CODE

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession() ;    // Will create new 
    session.setAttribute("timesLoggedIn", 0);
    session.setAttribute("pictureNames", null);
     // session.setAttribute("pictureNames", null);
    Integer accessCount = (Integer)session.getAttribute("timesLoggedIn") ;
    String pictureNames = request.getPathInfo();
    String pathName = (String)session.getAttribute("pictureNames");
    String id = session.getId();

    //start session
    //increment count by one
    //if count already implemented, don't implement.

    out.println(pathName);
      if (accessCount < 1 && pathName == null) {

           out.println("<h1>This is your first visit!</h1>");
           session.setAttribute("timesLoggedIn", 1);
           session.setAttribute("pictureNames", pictureNames);
             Utilities.IncreaseCount(out, pictureName);


        }

      out.println(pathName);
```

Comment: you are checking `pathName` for only `null` but not if it is changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page path with the servlet request API, such as `request.getPathInfo()`

You could then use this to create a session attribute key unique to the page. If there would be characters in the page path that are not permitted to be part of a session attribute key then you could obviously replace the characters in the string. It would be up to you to determine whether you would want to also consider query parameters as unique pages, e.g. `/page1?a=1` vs `/page1?a=2`

Then it would be trivial in your if/else to say if the key does not exist, put the value there with `1`. If the key is already in the session, do not increment it, just read the value to display it.

Be mindful that if you do consider query params unique pages and this would have different keys for `/page1?a=1` vs `/page1?a=2` it could be potentially dangerous for memory consumption as a nasty use who figures this out could in theory write a script to request many different pages using unique query params which would slowly but surely fill the session with lots of small bit of data but could eventually over a sustained period of time be some sort of denial of service via polluting your session storage.

Comment: I've tried implementing your suggestion. However i'm unable to increment different pictures. My logic for checking if the path has changed must be wrong. Updated my OP with my current thinking

Comment: I'm not sure I follow correctly what the issue you're having now is. In the else block, I think you no longer want to add 1 to `i` because you actually have the value `1` in there. Alternatively, you need not store an int at all any more, you could perhaps put the value `null` in there and just test for the presence or absence of the key - if it's no there put the key, if it is just display "logged in once". What are you trying to do here, e.g. if I hit the URL `/pictures/1` and `/pictures/2` you want to track the fact I've seen that at least once?

Comment: I'm a little confused about why there are counters or the message "You have visited this page " + i + " times! " if you want `i` to always be at most 1? Either I load the page that I've never seen and it says i've been here 0 times or I have been here before and it says 1 even if i've been here 100 times?

Comment: I was just having the messages in for testing to try and help me understand. I'll update my OP with my now current thinking, it increments all the time. Yea to answer your question i want to track that you've hit both pages once, but i don't want you to be able to refresh your page and keep the view count on increasing. I want one view per page, per session